# from voice_engine.source import Source ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'voice_engine'

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I am trying to create a program which takes in the direction of arrival of audio using a raspberry pi and Respeaker 4mic array.

I followed the steps on the below link and the installation was successful as shown in the screenshot.
https://pypi.org/project/voice_engine/

[screen shot of terminal location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmDMS.png)


When I run the python program, I get the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/doa.txt", line 9, in 
    from voice_engine.source import Source
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'voice_engine'

```
import sys
import time
from voice_engine.source import Source
from voice_engine.channel_picker import ChannelPicker
from voice_engine.doa_respeaker_4mic_array import DOA
```

I am using Python 3.7.3 (/usr/bin/python3)
(which is also the default for terminal)

I have tried everything I could think of and googled the error however no answers have helped.